# Finding an Image Within an Image in Java

Tags: java, image, matching

I have been trying for hours to make this work, but for some reason, it is not finding matches.  You can test it out with any image, but it should be taking a screenshot of the top left corner of the screen (1000px by 1000px) and finding the specified image within it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        import java.awt.Rectangle;
        import java.awt.Robot;
        import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.IOException;

        import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


        public class ImageRobotTester {

            /**
             * @param args
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                ImageRobot i = new ImageRobot();
                try {
                    BufferedImage settingsImage = ImageIO.read(new File("images/Dex.png"));
                    Robot r = new Robot();
                    BufferedImage screen = r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000));

                    i.subImage(settingsImage, screen);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        }
      import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class ImageRobot {

    public ImageRobot() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void subImage(BufferedImage needle, BufferedImage hayStack)
    {
        int xMatch = 0;
        int yMatch = 0;
        int possMatches = 0;
        try {
            for(int j = 0; j < hayStack.getHeight() - needle.getHeight(); j++)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < hayStack.getWidth() - needle.getWidth(); i++)
                {
                    BufferedImage hayStackSub = hayStack.getSubimage(i, j, needle.getWidth(), needle.getHeight());
                    if(hayStackSub.equals(needle))
                    {
                        System.out.println("match!");
                        xMatch = i;
                        yMatch = j;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Out of bounds! (" + xMatch + ", " + yMatch + ")");
        }

        System.out.println("(" + xMatch + ", " + yMatch + ")");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the image you are looking for displayed on the screen while you are testing it? I mean if you need to find a similar image, a straight pixel by pixel match has no chance of working.

Comment: `images/Dex.png`  A PNG might contain semi-transparent colors.  Be sure to skip checking those pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I am wrong, but are you trying to do some kind of image recognition here?
You are not searching for a sub-image that matches the reference image pixel by pixel, but you are searching for a *similar* image? Right?

In this case you need to move a small "window" over your big image (like you are doing right now with your double for loop), but instead of using "equals", use a properly trained neural network to tell if the image you are looking for is inside that window.

See this tutorial for details on how to build a NN based image recognizer:

http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/image_recognition.html

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm looking for the exact image.  As if trying to find where the Chrome logo is on my desktop, etc.

Comment: That is not an exact match either, because of color coding differences, edge smoothing, resizing etc. However there might be a less computationally intensive approximation algorithm available. eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis